# async Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I want to understand what Async function do in js.
If it actually runs code asynchronously then it should keep executing the code which is written after function call.

My code:

```
async function someWork(){

            let p=10;
            console.log("inside someWork");
            //Some calculations to spend time
            for(let i=0;i<100000000;i++){
                b=i**i;
                if(i==100000000-2){
                    console.log(i+" last Iteration, about to complete the calculation..");
                }
            }
            console.log(p+" I am done With Long work");
        }
        
        console.log("before calling somework async function");
        someWork();
        console.log("after calling somework async function");
```

output:

```
 before calling somework async function
 inside someWork
 99999998 last Iteration, about to complete the calculation..
 10 I am done With Long work
 after calling somework async function
```

However what I am expecting is:

```
 before calling somework async function
 after calling somework async function
 inside someWork
 99999998 last Iteration, about to complete the calculation..
 10 I am done With Long work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it actually runs code asynchronously...

An `async` function does not execute asynchronously. It runs synchronously, but returns a promise. Declaring a function with `async` only makes sense when it uses the keyword `await`, because that will be the point where the function returns to continue with the code *after* the function call, leaving the rest of its code for later, asynchronous execution.

For your desired output, there are many options:

1. Insert the line `await null;` at the top of your `async` function.
2. Don't use `async` and have your function called by `setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame`, `queueMicrotask`, or any other asynchronous API.
3. Create a Web Worker, and have the function executed by it. This will have the function executed by a different thread, potentially giving more concurrency.